# How to reschedule C# System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, timer, .net-4.5

I'm attempting to create a Session implementation. In order to complete it, I need to create Session timeouts. To do this, I decided I should use a Timer that executes after x seconds. However, if a request is received before that timer expires, then it should be rescheduled.

So, I have a timer:

```
using System.Threading.Timer;

public class SessionManager {
    private int timeToLive; //Initialized in the constructor.
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Session> sessions; //Populated in establishSession. Removed in abandonSession.

    public Session establishSession(...)
    {
        Session session = ...; //I have a session object here. It's been added to the dictionary.

        TimerCallback tcb = abandonSession;
        Timer sessionTimer = new Timer(tcb, null, timeToLive, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void abandonSession(Object stateInfo)
    {
        //I need to cancel the session here, which means I need to retrieve the Session, but how?
    }

    public void refreshSession(Session session)
    {
        //A request has come in; I have the session object, now I need to reschedule its timer. How can I get reference to the timer? How can I reschedule it?
    }
}
```

What I need help with:

1. I could make the `sessionTimer` a member of the `Session` object. That
   would give me access to the Timer object in `refreshSession()` but I
   don't know how to "reschedule" it.
2. I still don't have any idea how I can get a reference to the
   `Session` in `abandonSession()` callback. Is there a way to send the `Session` object in the `stateInfo`?

I was thinking I could store a reference to the `SessionManager` on the `Session` object, and have the callback reference a method on the `Session` object for the `abandonSession()` call. That seemed sloppy though. What do you think?

Please, let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: @dlev So don't actually remove/invalidate the session until it is requested. That would mean it would sit in my `sessions` Dictionary indefinitely, though. I could schedule a periodic task that iterated the `sessions` Dictionary, and removed old sessions I guess...

Comment: Yeah, that would be reasonable. Or you could even have a *single* timer, that culled clearly stale sessions every so often. Just an option; going with lots of timers (with lots of updates) doesn't scale all that well.

Comment: @dlev That's a good point. A cleanup task like that would fix my other issues as well with getting references to the sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[Change method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change.aspx)** to set a new invocation delay:

```
sessionTimer.Change(timeToLive, timeToLive)
```

As for getting a value in your callback method, the second parameter that you currently pass as **null** is your callback object... Your Timer callback method forces a signature of `object` and you can cast that object to your passed in type to use it.

```
var myState = new Something();
var sessionTimer = new Timer(tcb, myState, timeToLive, Timeout.Infinite);

...

public void abandonSession(Object stateInfo)
{
    var myState = (Something)stateInfo;
    //I need to cancel the session here, which means I need to retrieve the Session, but how?
}
```

Comment: Will that cancel the current invocation delay, and "reschedule" it essentially? `Changes the start time and the interval between method invocations for a timer.` was confusing. It sounds like `Change` wouldn't take place until after the current invocation.

Comment: If the current invocation has NOT yet fired, it will delay the firing of it to the new values. If it is CURRENTLY firing it will not affect the execution. This is known as a "race condition" and if your timer change is THAT close to expiration, I think it's usually OK to allow expiration to happen.

Comment: So, I can pass any object there? The examples showed an AutoResetEvent getting passed there.

Comment: Anything you want. Also make sure you null check it before casting it. :)